# Is there an Ubuntu developer installation which comes with full C/C++ development envirenment installed?

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++, make, gdb

I do not want to download source code for gnu gcc/g++/gdb/make...  and compile from scratch.  I am OK with downloading a built and ready to use set of packages.  But best of all, I am looking for an Ubuntu flavor which comes with that already installed.  Is there one?

Comment: You won'r need to compile those from scratch on *any* binary-based distro (including Ubuntu) - they can be installed straightforwardly using the package manager

Answer (score 1):

Check out the package "build-essential", that gets you gcc and make.

I don't know of a flavor with the tools pre-installed. If I did, I'd still probably pick mainstream Ubuntu and install the package, rather than use a less-mainstream distro.

Comment: You're right. Installing a development environment takes only a couple apt commands, so there's no real need for a whole different distro.